# How to allow the table to expand vertically incase it contain long text

Tags: html, css

I am working on an Asp.net MVC web application, and i define the following for the tables layout inside the CSS file.-

I am constructing the Tables using the following code:-

```
<div class="box-content">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
 <thead>
<tr>
//code goes here
```

and i define the following inside CSS file related to formatting the the box-content:-

```
.box-content{
padding:10px;
}
.box-content .nav-tabs{
margin-right:-10px;
margin-left:-10px;
}
.box-content.buttons{
min-height:297px;
}
```

and i define the following inside CSS file related to formatting the table:-

```
table {
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.table th {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.table thead th {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.table caption + thead tr:first-child th,
.table caption + thead tr:first-child td,
.table colgroup + thead tr:first-child th,
.table colgroup + thead tr:first-child td,
.table thead:first-child tr:first-child th,
.table thead:first-child tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}
.table tbody + tbody {
  border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
}
.table-condensed th,
.table-condensed td {
  padding: 4px 5px;
}
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  *border-collapse: collapsed;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.table-bordered th,
.table-bordered td {
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.table-bordered caption + thead tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered caption + tbody tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered caption + tbody tr:first-child td,
.table-bordered colgroup + thead tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered colgroup + tbody tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered colgroup + tbody tr:first-child td,
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child th,
.table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th:first-child,
.table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child td:first-child {
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
}
.table-bordered thead:first-child tr:first-child th:last-child,
.table-bordered tbody:first-child tr:first-child td:last-child {
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
}
.table-bordered thead:last-child tr:last-child th:first-child,
.table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child td:first-child {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
}
.table-bordered thead:last-child tr:last-child th:last-child,
.table-bordered tbody:last-child tr:last-child td:last-child {
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
}
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td,
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.table tbody tr:hover td,
.table tbody tr:hover th {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

But the problem i am facing is that in case the table contains long text inside any of its cells,  it will go out of the box-content as follow:-
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try to add the following code to the cell's

```
word-wrap: break-word;
display: inline-block;
```

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/HUNJE/1/

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this will make the table unreadable as columns will be displayed as-if there are merged together, and not align with the table header

Comment: i define Table-layout:fixed; & word-wrap:break-word;. And it worked fine, but not sure if this is the right approach ?

Answer (score 1):

try the css rules:

```
table{ table-layout: fixed;}
table td{ white-space: normal;}
```

this will do that, 1. the table holds the cells width that you supplied, 2. `white-space:normal` or even `word-wrap: break-word;` will force the text content to be slitted if necessary to keep the column width.

Comment: i define 1.table-layout:fixed; and 2.word-wrap:break-word;. And it worked fine, but not sure if this is the right approach ?